# Facebook Comments/box not displaying on Wordpress blog posts

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-comments

I am working on integrating facebook comments onto a site and have run into an issue that I cannot figure out. At this moment I am using Facebook Comments Plugin by Alex Moss, however I am having the same issue with every facebook plugin I have tried and even when attempting to do it manually (using the code generator in facebook's developer dashboard) no facebook comment box will show.

Below you will see a link to one of the blogs posts:
http://cultofamericana.com/2016/04/03/unseasonable-seasons-sit-down/

If you scroll down to the bottom of the post you will see a section that says "Commentary" which is the header for the facebook comments section, however no facebook comment box shows up below it. The app ID is loaded into the plugin and the setup for the plugin has been followed and rechecked but I've had no luck. (Also, tried uninstalling the plugin and reinstalling/tried other plugins, same issue)

When checking the CSS there is nothing that would be hiding the box and I don't see any errors coming up in the console. Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Shows up fine for me – I see the input box where I could post a new comment, and my Facebook profile picture next to it … Go check your browser console for any errors or messages that content was blocked. Also check your browser’s privacy settings, resp. the extensions/add-ons you might have installed.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for confirming that you were seeing it. It turns out it was the extension "Disconnect" for Google Chrome that was hiding it. I was not aware that it actually hid facebook comment boxes until now. I've been tearing my hair out over here. Thanks again!